# ngRoute Not Routing to /login when going to /

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Very weird scenario here. I have my app with a bunch of routes that work when I navigate to them. My problem is when I first load example.com/#/ and a user is not logged in it should route to example.com/#/login and load the login template and controller. My issue is the URL bar updates the url to have example.com/#/login but the route does not follow through displaying the template and stays on the / route template. Below is the code for my app.js

```
/*
 *  Main AngularJS Web App
 */
var app = angular.module('angularWebApp',
  ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap',
  'angularWebApp.loginController',
  'angularWebApp.headController',
  'angularWebApp.indexController',
  'angularWebApp.multikeyModalController',
  'angularWebApp.forgotPasswordController',
  'angularWebApp.machineProfileController',
  'angularWebApp.monthlyReportingController',
  'angularWebApp.headerDirectives',
  'angularWebApp.indexDirectives',
  'angularWebApp.coreDirectives']);

/**
 * Configure the Routes
 */

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
      when("/",
        { templateUrl: "view/index.html", controller: "indexController" }).
      when("/login",
        { templateUrl: "view/login.html", controller: "loginController" }).
      when("/forgot",
        { templateUrl: "view/passwordForgot.html", controller: "forgotPasswordController"}).
      // event more routes here ...
      otherwise( { redirectTo: "/" });
    }).
    run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
      if ($rootScope.loggedInUser === undefined || $rootScope.loggedInUser === null) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        //console.log($rootScope.loggedInUser);
        if ( next.templateUrl === "view/login.html" || next.templateUrl === "view/passwordForgot.html") {
        } else {
          $location.path("/login");
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Any help to see what is going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

#### Update 1

I get a compile error in the console that started happening after I started calling some $timeout functions. The ability for the correct route to load to /login was happening before this error but for references sake:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
    at angular.js:6418
    at forEach (angular.js:339)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:6413)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4118)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:3971)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4118)
    at angular.js:3936
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4077)
    at addDirective (angular.js:7695)
    at collectDirectives (angular.js:7040)
```

#### Update 2

I just fixed the console error above. I had a directive I no longer used and instead of commenting out the .directive I just did its contents which needs a return. Hence the compile error. After doing this and trying the example.com/ url again I still have the same issue as above.

Comment: Do you get any error message in your Console ?

Comment: I am currently  trying to resolve a compile error but it was happening before that error ever appeared. The compile error I will update the article above

Comment: Can you fix that `compile` error first and see if the changing `route` works ? I doubt that there is some problem with your `loginController`

Comment: hey @themyth92 I just fixed the error and updated what happened with it in Update2. Still not working :S

Comment: Are you sure the `index.html` and `login.html` is not the same ? And can you check when the browser change `path` to `/login`, does it send a `GET` request to `server` to load `login.html` ?

Comment: I recreated the issue in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pNrbInnw2wJYBktOz2AJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if you do the `$location.path()` change inside `$rootScope.$apply()` it will work fine. Can't figure out why, but see the below snippet. I modified the code slightly to make it work inside a snippet without multiple html files, but you get the gist of what I did.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          controller: 'homeCtrl',
          template: '<span>This is the home page</span><br /><strong>currentPath: </strong><span ng-bind="currentPath"></span>'
        })
        .when('/login', {
          controller: 'loginCtrl',
          template: '<span>This is the login page</span><br /><strong>currentPath: </strong><span ng-bind="currentPath"></span><br /><button ng-click="setUser()">Set User</button>'
        })
        .when('/forgot', {
          controller: 'forgotCtrl',
          template: '<span>This is the forgotten password page</span><br /><strong>currentPath: </strong><span ng-bind="currentPath"></span>'
        })
    }
  ])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (!$rootScope.loggedInUser) {
          console.log(next);
          if (!(next.template === '<span>This is the login page</span><br /><strong>currentPath: </strong><span ng-bind="currentPath"></span><br /><button ng-click="setUser()">Set User</button>')) {
            $timeout(function() {
              $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                console.log('user not logged in and not going to login or forgotten password page');
                $location.url('/login');
              })
            });
          }
        } else {
          console.log('user is logged in ', $rootScope.loggedInUser);
        }
      })
    }
  ])
  .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
      console.log('in homeCtrl');
      $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
    }
  ])
  .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
      console.log('in loginCtrl');
      $scope.currentPath = $location.path();

      $scope.setUser = function() {
        $rootScope.loggedInUser = {
          'name': 'Ben Black'
        };
        $location.path('/');
      }
    }
  ])
  .controller('forgotCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
      console.log('in forgotCtrl');
      $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<duiv ng-view>
  </div>

</html>
```

**Edit** Made sure it was working by populating `loggedInUser` with a button click on the `loginCtrl`

Comment: It works! I am getting an error that the $digest is already in progress is there any way to fix that so my console would be error free?

Comment: I edited it so it's wrapped in a `$timeout` call, that should fix it. Can't figure out why it would work but give a `$digest` error. This is where my knowledge of angular starts to get a bit rough around the edges. If someone else comes along that knows what's causing it that would be great.

Comment: Hey @Ben-Black That worked. I was doing it wrong and placing the $timeout inside the $apply. It makes sense to wrap it in a timeout now bc the digest of the current DOM and directives is probably still in progress since it is being called so early. I appreciate all the help!